# Google cloud datafusion how to accept self-signed certificates

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-data-fusion

We are just starting to use google cloud data fusion for our ETL.

We have a use case to hit a server(self-signed) and get some info using the http-plugin in the data fusion product.

In my pipeline, i am turning off SSL verification to accept any certificates but getting an error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <on000120.aeo.ae.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []
```

Help text for the field also suggests to urn it off. See image.

[image]

Could someone please help?

Comment: What version of http plugin do you use?

Comment: v1.2.0. We have enterprise edition and this is the only version available in the Hub. Is there any later versions and how can i pull that in?

Comment: You can find [here](https://github.com/data-integrations/http) http-plugin v1.3.0, that can be uploaded to DF instance.

Comment: Do you have a problem only with this Java based http client? Have you tried to establish unsecured connection from within the other http commands sender?

Answer (score 2):

I followed the instructions at https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/ to generate the key and crt files, so I had a file called v3.ext (which includes subjectAltName) and used that to generate the server.crt file. When I started my server with these files, I was able to deploy and run a pipeline using HTTP source from that local HTTPS server. How did you generate your crt and key? Would you please describe the plugins you're using?

Comment: This seems like it's better formatted for a comment clarifying the question.  Screenshots of all the actions you took would definitely be helpful for a question like this.  Welcome to SO!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that issue that you've reported is not connected with Data Fusion runtime environment, but might be supposedly related the target HTTPS web server SSL/TLS configuration. Most of the time this issue occurs when the common name or *[SAN](https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm)(Subject Alternative Name)* of your SSL/TLS Certificate does not match the domain or address that you hit in HTTP call, hence this page is not listed in SAN's list and I can suppose that you didn't add any of domain names there.

As far as I know Data Fusion [*http-plugin*](https://github.com/data-integrations/http), which is based on Java HTTP Client implementation, promotes **HostnameVerifier** [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html?is-external=true), that is used for URL's hostname and the server's identification hostname verification during establishing handshake between parties, you may take a look at the source [code](https://github.com/data-integrations/http/blob/develop/src/main/java/io/cdap/plugin/http/source/common/http/SSLConnectionSocketFactoryCreator.java) and find inherited method `getDefaultHostnameVerifier()` as well. Therefore, this can lead to the error, during http client intentions to launch SSL/TLS connection channel.

Even though, you turned of trust keystore certificate inspection in the plugin settings, the issue will persist because hostname validation still failing.